# strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given - when I make eloquent query

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm making an web app with Laravel as Api and Vue.js for the front.

I wan't to return a collection of objects but I have an error and I can't fix it.

> strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

```
public function orderSearch (Request $request) {
        $data = $request->all();
        $aa = $data['search'];
        $orders = Order::whereHas(['customer' => function ($query) use ($aa){
            $query->where('firstname','LIKE','%' . $aa . '%')->orWhere('lastname','LIKE','%' . $aa . '%');
        }])->get();
        return $orders;
    }
```

my variable `$aa` is working fine and my relation between Order and Customer is fine.

**Order.php**

```
 public function customer() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Customer');
    }
```

**Customer.php**

```
 public function order() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Order');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your `Order::whereHas` syntax is not correct it must be `string` instead of array.

something like:

```
public function orderSearch (Request $request) {
        $data = $request->all();
        $aa = $data['search'];
        $orders = Order::whereHas('customer', function ($query) use ($aa){
            $query->where('firstname','LIKE','%' . $aa . '%')->orWhere('lastname','LIKE','%' . $aa . '%');
        })->get();
        return $orders;
    }
```